# How can i create waypoints array of the terrain area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a number of flying objects and i need to give them some waypoints.
What i want is to make them fly all around the terrain area in a free style.

Is it possinle to do it with waypoints ?

In the screenshot on the Main Camera inspector on the Main.cs script i have Instance Points the Size is 1 with Element 0. The Element is on the Hierarchy the InstancePoint. In the InstancePoint i have the script Trace that get Way Points.

In this waypoints the objects should fly between. Now the Way Points size is 0, i wonder if it's possible to create some GameObjects as waypoints that will be the Terrain area so the object will fly around the Terrain area but as much as free style and not just between 3-4 waypoints ? Or maybe the logic should be something else at all without way points ?

[image: Screenshot]

This is the Trace script:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Trace: MonoBehaviour
{
  public Material normalState;
  public Material activeState;

  public WayPoint[] wayPoints;
  private WayPoint curWP = null;


  public void Start()
  {
    foreach( var wp in wayPoints )
      SetTrigger(wp, false);

    if( wayPoints.Length > 0 )
    {
      curWP = wayPoints[0];
      SetTrigger( curWP, true );
    }
  }

  void SetTrigger( WayPoint wp, bool value )
  {
    wp.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = value;
    wp.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = value ? activeState : normalState;
  }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
  [UnityEditor.MenuItem ("GameEditor/Collect route from priority of waypoints")]
  static void DoSomething ()
  {
    Trace curTrace = (Trace)FindObjectOfType( typeof(Trace) );

    var list = new List<WayPoint>();
    var rgx = new Regex(@"\d+$");

    //Selection.gameObjects doesn't hold selection order
    foreach( var obj in FindObjectsOfType(typeof(WayPoint)) )
    {
      var wp = (WayPoint)obj;

      list.Add(wp);
      wp.name = rgx.Split(obj.name)[0] + wp.editorPriority.ToString("D2");
      wp.trace = curTrace;
    }

    list.Sort( (t1, t2) => t1.editorPriority - t2.editorPriority );
    //ths.wayPoints = list.Select( (v) => v.gameObject ).ToArray();
    curTrace.wayPoints = list.ToArray();
  }
#endif

  public Vector3 GetAtractionPoint()
  {
    return curWP.transform.position;
  }

  public void NextWayPoint()
  {
    SetTrigger( curWP, false );

    var nextIndex = Array.FindIndex( wayPoints, (v) => v == curWP ) + 1;

    if( nextIndex == wayPoints.Length )
      nextIndex = 0;

    curWP = wayPoints[nextIndex];
    SetTrigger( curWP, true );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to get your flying object to behave this way with scripts it would be much easier to use the animator that comes with Unity.

You can choose the different locations(waypoints) with keyframes and use the built in tools to create smooth animation curves. Then if you need this behaviour to change just use a script to switch animation to something more appropriate.

Introductory videos on the topic > [Animation in Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation)